# How to setup gitlab pipeline with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I want to setup CI/CD for my project using Jenkins and Gitlab. How can i integrate these tools for my project

Answer (score 0):

The Question is very broad but in general you would configure a webhook in Jenkins with something like the Generic Webhook Plugin, then setup a pipeline (lots of resources online).
Then you'd have to configure Gitlab to call the url of the webhook once something was pushed.

If you get this to work you would have a pretty solid setup.